# Error with minimization of NProbability

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

```
Minimize[{NProbability[(1 - 2 g)*y + g^.5 + s < 
x, {x, y} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]], 0 < g < 1 && 0 < s < 1}, {g, s}]
```

This code gives an error message from NIntegrate (`NIntegrate::izero`)

Any ideas why the error message? How can I solve the problem? 
If I run a contour plot of the objective over the constrained area I get something that looks well behaved:

```
ContourPlot[NProbability[(1 - 2 g)*y + g^.5 + s < x, {x, y} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]], {g, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a **transformed distribution** solves the error message.

Define:

```
 Fz = TransformedDistribution[(1 -2g)*y + g^.5 + s - x, {y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[], x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[]}]
```

And use it with the `Probability[]` command:

```
Minimize[{Probability[z < 0, z \[Distributed] Fz],0 < g < 1 && 0 < s < 1}, {g, s}]
```

This yields the following output:

```
{0., {g -> 0.753979, s -> 0.979782}}
```